# Fill sparse matrix parallel

Tags: c#, sparse-matrix, numeric, allocation, indexoutofrangeexception

I have a sparse-matrix from `Extreme.Mathematics.LinearAlgebra` like:

```
SparseMatrix<double> J = Matrix.CreateSparse<double>(amountI, amountJ);
```

Now I want to fill it in a parallel loop, since filling it in parallel shound be way faster.

```
Parallel.For(0, amountI, i =>
{
    for (int j = 0; j < amountJ; j++)
        J[i, j] = random.Next();
});
```

This gives me the error: out of range exception.

However, for a normal for loop, it works pretty fine.

```
for (int i = 0; i < amountI; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < amountJ; j++)
        J[i, j] = random.Next();
}
```

Also, if I use a 2D array instead of a sparse matrix it works fine.

```
double[,] M = new double[amountI, amountJ];
Parallel.For(0, amountI, i =>
{
    for (int j = 0; j < amountJ; j++)
        M[i, j] = random.Next();
});
```

**How do I achieve, to fill a sparse matrix in parallel without running into out of range exceptions?**

Answer (score 1):

*I know this is a little bit late but better than nothing.*

The Sparse matrix is something completely different from a normal array. It uses indices of rows and columns, to store only the non-zero values of the matrix. For further information I guess you should read the docs of Extreme.

In general: The backend of a sparse matrix has to reallocate memory every time you modify the underlying data. So given the case you loop normally, the allocations will happen in sync and you are fine. As soon as multiple threads try to modify the matrix, you will get into trouble, because on one thread you allocated new memory, which is immediately overwritten by another thread, giving you an exception on the original thread.

**So:** Parallel filling of sparse matrices **wont work**. I didn't find a proper library which gives the possibility of writing to a sparse matrix in parallel yet.